# NOT insert blank/null field into database using coldfusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

How do I **avoid** inserting a null or blank field into a database using coldfusion?

The input box on the form is this:

```
 <cfloop index="x" from="1" to="5"> 
 <cfoutput>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="ITIProgramName#x#" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50"  ></td>
    <td><input name="ITIProgVer#x#" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50"  ></td>
  </tr>
 </cfoutput>
 </cfloop>
```

action form as this:

```
<cfquery datasource="ITSReporting" name="InsertQuery">
    INSERT INTO ITIPRO
        (   ServerID,
            ServerName,
            <cfif #Form["ITIProgramName#x#"]# neq="">ProgramName,</cfif>
            <cfif #Form["ITIProgVer#x#"]# neq="">CurrentProgVer,</cfif>
            LastUser,
            UpDone  )
VALUES
        (   '#Form.ServerID#',
            '#Form.ServerName#',
            <cfqueryparam value="#Form["ITIProgramName#x#"]#" >,
            <cfqueryparam value="#Form["ITIProgVer#x#"]#" >,
            '#CGI.Auth_User#',
            #CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#
                        )
</cfquery>
```

How can I get the database to NOT accept the null value? The users does not always need to enter information in all the fields.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to put instead? A zero-length string? If you don't want to allow NULLs, you shouldn't exclude those columns from your insert. And probably should set the database to disallow NULLs in those columns.

Comment: Your `<cfif ...>` syntax is incorrect. You have `neq=""`, it should be `neq ""`. You also need the same `<cfif ...>` condition check around your `<cfqueryparam ...>` tags. That should work.

Comment: Your question does not really make sense. You say you do **not** want to allow nulls. Yet your code IS attempting to insert null values when some of the form fields are empty. Exactly what do you want to happen if those two form fields are empty ...?

Comment: Leigh, as you mention my code is attempting to insert null when the form fields are empty. My form has static input  and I am attempting to insert only the ones that has some text on them. The empty fields should not be insert in my db, no null, no empty.

Comment: Back to @FishBelowtheIce's question.  If you don't want a null value or empty string, what do you want?

Comment: Hm.. that is still not clear. Are you saying you want to skip the entire `insert` if both of those form fields are empty?

Comment: Yes Leigh. I should only insert the forms that are not empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing some basic concepts: [table column versus row/record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_%28database%29).

Executing the `INSERT` command will **always** add a new record to your db table. Omitting a few columns from the insert list has absolutely no effect on that. It simply causes the database to insert default values into whatever columns you omitted. In this case, `null`.

If your goal is to skip the *entire* `INSERT` when those form fields are empty, you need different logic. Check the values of the form fields first. Only run the query if at least one them is populated.

Not tested, but something along these lines:

```
<!--- If at least one of the fields is NOT an empty string .. --->
<cfif Form["ITIProgramName#x#"] neq "" OR
      Form["ITIProgVer#x#"] neq "">

     <--- create a new record --->
     <cfquery datasource="ITSReporting" name="InsertQuery">
         INSERT INTO ITIPRO
         (   ServerID
           , ServerName
           , ProgramName
           , CurrentProgVer
           , LastUser
           , UpDone  
         )
         VALUES
         (   
            <cfqueryparam value="#Form.ServerID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , <cfqueryparam value="#Form.ServerName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , <cfqueryparam value="#Form['ITIProgramName'& x]#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , <cfqueryparam value="#Form['ITIProgVer'& x]#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , <cfqueryparam value="#CGI.Auth_User#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           , <cfqueryparam value="#Now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
         )
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

It is worth reiterating a few comments I made on your other thread:

> - Always use [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) on variable query parameters. (Be sure to specify the `cfsqltype` that matches the target column). cfqueryparam helps protect your db
>     against sql injection. It can also improve performance when executing
>     the same query multiple times, as you are doing.
> - To ensure data integrity, do not forget to wrap the loop in
>     a `cftransaction`. That will ensure all of the inserts succeed or fail as one unit.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap both your into and values set in a conditional if you didn't want to insert at all. Though your DB will probably set a default value usually null unless you specify otherwise.

```
<cfif #Form["ITIProgramName#x#"]# neq "">ProgramName,</cfif>
...
<cfif #Form["ITIProgramName#x#"]# neq ""><cfqueryparam value="#Form["ITIProgramName#x#"]#" >,</cfif>
```

Comment: Jdunham and @Miguel-F, thanks for your comment. Code shows no error now but it is still inserting blank spaces in my db.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert null values instead of blanks, you can use the `null` attribute of `cfqueryparam`

There are a variety of ways to do this, but using the code from above you would do this:

```
ProgramName,
...
<cfif #Form["ITIProgramName#x#"]# neq "">
    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim(Form["ITIProgramName#x#"])#" >
<cfelse>
    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="" null = "yes" >
</cfif>
,
```

Note that I took the liberty of trimming your input so that empty spaces evaluate to an empty string.  If you don't want that, leave it off.